# Any ideas for a SQL "set analysis" application? (sql server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Does anybody have any ideas for something that can quickly analyze regular tables to derive a set of populations? I'm going to say "regular" tables because I'm not wanting to dive into Analytical Services and throw cubes at it.

I have queries that define different set of populations. I want to be able to see how many items in one set reside in another set. That then defines a third population. This keeps building out to dozens and dozens of sets and the layering of the populations increases.

I'm currently doing this all in SQL with temp tables and CTEs but as things get more complex, so do the dependencies, and even making small changes is becoming a burden.

Answer (score 1):

I had to google what you meant by "set analysis" I think you are referring to the data mining tools that you point at some data and it makes an attempt group them into categories that might be meaningful, like "best customers" "occasional customers" etc.

There was a .NET Rocks show where they interviewed Seth Juarez who is working on a [Machine Learning library](http://machine.codeplex.com/). From his [blog](http://sethjuarez.com/) I would infer that this is solving a similar problem.

The [data mining tag on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=data%20mining) also has a lot of people who seem to be asking similar questions about finding data mining libraries that are either free or easy.

Comment: Yeah, it is data mining but when I googled that, I didn't see anything that targeted the type of analysis that I wanted to do.  It was all OLAP and cubes. "Set analysis" was the closest I could think of because it had a direct mapping to set theory in that I deal with intersections, unions, and compliments.  I'll go check out posts with that tag.  thanks.